# $x$ is within 3 units of $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to use absolute value notation to represent the phrase "$x$ is within 3 units of $c$". Which of the following is the correct answer? (i) or (ii)?

(i) $|x-c|<3$, (ii) $|x-c|\leq{3}$

Comment: that's hard to say....  Both could be used,  it sorta depends on the context...  I personally think of (ii)  when I see this, but you really need to define "within"

Comment: "Within" doesn't seem to be standard terminology. If you want to use it, you can just define it yourself as either (i) or (ii), whichever is more comfortable. If you've seen it in another text, then you need to guess the meaning from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is fairly ambiguous and either expression could be used depending on your interpretation of within. If you are writing a solution to an exercise, I would advise stating

> "$x$ is within $3$ units of $c$, i.e. $\lvert x-c\rvert\:(\le\:\text{or}\:<)\:3"$

That is, make it clear how you have interpreted this imprecise English expression.